# Is there a way to choose a "horizontal center" of a TikZ picture?

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment

I want my TikZ figure to be horizontally centered around a coordinate. In this example I want the horizontal center of the figure to be at the center of the square, x=2, but a text node extends beyond the square, which moves the center to e.g. x=2.1.

[image]

The reason I want this is for the square to be aligned properly when placed in a float in my document. I've usually "solved" this by placing an opposite fake element, in this case a white text or `hphantom` node, to extend the left border equally. I've also manually placed invisible elements to extend the left border. However, I'm sure there's a better solution that doesn't require manual adjustments?

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) rectangle (4,4);
\draw[fill=black] (3,3.5) circle (0.1) --++ (0,1) node[anchor=south] {label extends border};
\draw[fill=black] (2,2) circle (0.1) --++ (0,-0.5) node[anchor=north] {actual center of figure};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This is the figure I want:

[image]

Comment: I am not sure to understand... would `\draw [use as bounding box] (0,0) rectangle (4,4);` solve your problem? This will cut out the "extending" label, of course, when imported and clipped.

Comment: @Rmano I want to produce a figure that includes all of the elements in the figure (including the "extending" label), but also padding on the left side such that the center of the figure is at x=2. Does that make sense?

Comment: @Rmano I added a figure where I've added the left margin, maybe it's clearer now what I'm trying to do

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (o) at (2,2);
\draw (0,0) rectangle (4,4);
\draw[fill=black] (3,3.5) circle[radius=0.1] -- ++(0,1) node[above] {label extends border};
\draw[fill=black] (o) circle[radius=0.1] -- ++(0,-0.5) node[below] {actual center of figure};
\useasboundingbox let \p1=(o), \p2=(current bounding box.south west), \p3=(current bounding box.north east) in ({\x1-(\x3-\x1)},\y2) rectangle (\x3,\y3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Rectangle with two dots and text]

Comment: yes, +1 for being (much) less lazy than me... ;-)

Comment: Fantastic, thank you both!

Answer (score 4):

I understand that you want an automatic way to extend the (horizontal) figure bounding box so that it is symmetrical around the center of your rectangle.

One way of solving this is the following: I changed the "center point" to `(0,0)` for simplicity --- it's not difficult, just tedious, to adapt to a generic center.

At the end of the figure, I get the `x` coordinate of the `east` and `west` anchor for the `current bounding box` shape and then draw an invisible line (not stroked) between the "inverted" limits.

```latex
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw  (-2,-2) rectangle (2,2);
    \draw[fill=black] (1,1.5) circle (0.1) --++ (0,1) node[anchor=south] {label extends border};
    \draw[fill=black] (0,0) circle (0.1) --++ (0,-0.5) node[anchor=north] {actual center of figure};
    \path let \p1 = (current bounding box.west), 
              \p2 = (current bounding box.east) 
          in (-\x1,0) -- (-\x2,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could hide the width of the label with `\makebox[0pt]{label extends border}` and add a horizontal margin to your image which will be symmetrical:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border={0.7cm 0cm}]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) rectangle (4,4);
\draw[fill=black] (3,3.5) circle (0.1) --++ (0,1) node[anchor=south] {\makebox[0pt]{label extends border}};
\draw[fill=black] (2,2) circle (0.1) --++ (0,-0.5) node[anchor=north] {actual center of figure};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or you could use `overlay` to prevent chosen elements from influencing the bounding box:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border={0.7cm}]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) rectangle (4,4);
\draw[fill=black] (3,3.5) circle (0.1) --++ (0,1) node[anchor=south,overlay] {label extends border};
\draw[fill=black] (2,2) circle (0.1) --++ (0,-0.5) node[anchor=north] {actual center of figure};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If I understand this correctly, the 0.7cm would need to be changed when the text changed, and the makebox-solution only works with a text node, not other kinds of elements? I was hoping for a more general solution. This is the kind of "tricks" I've been using so far, but I feel like I'm spending too much effort calibrating margins.

Comment: @Anna yes, but the result will automatically be symmetrical. Your margins just need to big enough, they don't need to be calibrated. You could also use the `overlay` option which works with all kinds of elements in a tikz picture.